# Не правильное отображение русских символов при использовании Node.js

Tags: node.js

Написал код на Node.js, запустил сервер, но почему-то вместо русского текста там отображаются кракозябры. Прилагаю cкрин :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcG1y.png]

Есть ли решение данной проблемы?

Comment: кодировку поменяйте.И будет вам счастья

Comment: Проблема в том, что он как раз таки читает кодировку UTF-8, но только на английском, вместо русского он почему-то выводит те символы.

Comment: Какая у вас среда разработки ?

Comment: Web Storm, могу приложить скрин кода, если поможет.

Comment: посмотрите какая кодировка указана в ответ от сервера. это можно сделать в chrome dev tools

Comment: А какую кодировку пишет сервер в Header? Ну и конечно надо точно знать какая кодировка используется в самом *.js , её показывает например Notepad++

Comment: Я уже разобрался,спасибо. Проблема была в том,что не стояли те настройки в File Encodings + у меня почему-то не читался тег <meta charset ="utf-8">

Answer (score 1):

Есть предположение, что у вас в самой среде разработки стоит не та кодировка.

У меня были похожие проблемы. Но когда я сменил кодировку самой **IDEA**, то все заработало. Смотрите в правый нижний угол:

[image: правый нижний угол]

Проверьте глобальные настройки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению,не помогло,даже после перезагрузки Web Storm и сервера.Кодировку проверил,стоит UTF-8.

Comment: попробуйте utf-16

Comment: Еще вариант - постмотреть в глобальных настройках. Обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Попробовал поставить как и стандартные настройки, так и UTF-8, но не помогло.

Comment: Daminstev, спасибо, я с утра понял в чем проблема. Она была в том,что не стояли те настройки в File Encodings + у меня почему-то не отображался тег <meta charset ="utf-8">.

Answer (score 0):

Сама столкнулась с такой же проблемой, хотя кодировка в самой IDE стояла верная.
Вот как я это исправила:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
```

[image: Явное указание кодировки]

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код текстом, а не картинкой.